# How is it possible for two domains to use the same resource

Tags: php, redirect, dns, cpanel

I have a domain X and a domain Y.

My original domain is X which has 1GIG host. Now, I need a second domain without any redirection to happen. I need to use exactly the same host for the second domain. So, it means, a website reachable by two different domains.

I have set parked domains, but when I do so the browser says the domain is not yet activated, while when I use addon domain with redirection enabled, it points toward the site which also changes the browser URL which I do not want.

What should be done to keep the browser's URL bar shows the domain X  when the user entered the X in the browser, and shows the domain Y when user entered Y.

I use **cPanel**.

thanks in advance

Comment: this question is off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: it is not 100% off topic, still you down-vote me and make me probably close to be blocked

Comment: it is off-topic 100%. it got nothing common programming this site is up to. Set up your dns correctly, then set up you httpd. If you do not know how, this is not the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offtopic or not:

> I have set parked domains, but when I do so the browser says the
>   domain is not yet activated

If you have a problem with a Cpanel, which is a non free software, get support from it. It's a must, because you pay (to anybody) to use it.

Addon domain is the right way to do, using without the redirect. Simply point it to public_html folder.